# object length is zero and unable to read values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown using javascript and i am unable to loop in through the values returned from the backend application, The object length is returned as 0 even though I have values on it

Below is the object

[image]

and This is the javascript snippet

```
 for (key in swaggerlist) {
    console.log(key)
    if (!swaggerlist.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
      var obj = swaggerlist[key];
        for (var prop in obj) {
          if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
            if(params["url"] == obj[prop]){
              option += '<option value="'+ obj[prop] + '" selected>' + obj[prop] + '</option>\n';
          } else {
              option += '<option value="'+obj[prop] + '">' + obj[prop] + '</option>\n';
        }
     console.log(obj[prop])
  }
  }
```

I am able to read the below one using the above function

[image]

How to fix this one and loop in through the object to get the values?

Comment: console.log lazy loads results, I agree with str

Comment: The blue [i] is telling me it is loaded dynamically so are you trying to eat the pizza before it is delivered?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.keys` to get an array of keys.  Then loop over those.

```
var swaggerKeys = Object.keys(swaggerlist);
swaggerKeys.forEach((key) => {
    //Access property
    var someVal = swaggerlist[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to loop on the array in the "`interstitials`" prop.

You get an object with a `interstitials` property who contains your items inside an array.

```js
var server_resp = {
  interstitials:["some data","some other data"]
}

server_resp.interstitials.forEach(item => {
  $("#mySelect").append(`<option>${item}</option>`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```